# load model saved by tensorflow v1 using keras or tensorflow v2

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow1.15

I found a pre trained model online saved using tensorflow v1 Saver object in [here](https://git.tu-berlin.de/rsim/BigEarthNet-S2_43-classes_models). My goal is to load this model and fine tune it, but I have never used tensorflow v1 before and I was wandering is it is possible to load this model and then fine tune it using tensorflow 2 or, even better, in keras? and if it is possible, how do I do it?

The pre trained model has three files, a VGG16.data-00000-of-00001, a VGG16.index and a VGG16.meta. I am using tensorflow in python 3

Comment: Nope most likely you can't as the weights were trained with tensorflow 1

Comment: But you can add write your own network for it seems kind of easy though, its just using a backbone then add a single fully connected layer for classification. Although i can be wrong since i just browse around the repo

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975886/tensorflow-load-resnet50-model-for-transfer-learning-from-bigearthnet-with-meta