# TensorFlow Load ResNet50 model for transfer learning from BigEarthNet with .meta, .index and .data-00000-of-00001 files, ValueError FusedBatchNormGrad

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, transfer-learning

I'm trying to load a ResNet50 model from BigEarthNet, https://git.tu-berlin.de/rsim/BigEarthNet-S2_19-classes_models,

1. First I unzip the model files in Google Colab:

`!unzip /content/drive/MyDrive/malaria_project/ResNet50.zip Archive:  /content/drive/MyDrive/malaria_project/ResNet50.zip creating: ResNet50/ inflating: ResNet50/ResNet50_BigEarthNet-19_labels.meta   inflating: ResNet50/ResNet50_BigEarthNet-19_labels.index   inflating: ResNet50/ResNet50_BigEarthNet-19_labels.data-00000-of-00001`

2. Import older version of tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf 
tf.enable_resource_variables()
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

3. Load the model graph from the meta file:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:    
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/content/ResNet50/ResNet50_BigEarthNet-19_labels.meta')
```

Which gives the following error:

`InvalidArgumentError: Node 'gradients/resnet_v1_50/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1_grad/FusedBatchNormGrad' has an _output_shapes attribute inconsistent with the GraphDef for output #3: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 0 and 2048. Shapes are [0] and [2048].`

and similarly

`ValueError: Node 'gradients/resnet_v1_50/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1_grad/FusedBatchNormGrad' has an _output_shapes attribute inconsistent with the GraphDef for output #3: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 0 and 2048. Shapes are [0] and [2048].`

A similar post here: https://github.com/lindawangg/COVID-Net/issues/107 , but that is for a different model and I'm not sure how to apply their solution.
And this question is very similar, but there are no real answers: [load model saved by tensorflow v1 using keras or tensorflow v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67140783/load-model-saved-by-tensorflow-v1-using-keras-or-tensorflow-v2)

Does anyone know how I can load the model from the .meta, .index and .data files?